# MongoException with message ''\\0' not allowed in key

Tags: c#, php, mongodb

I'm getting this error while trying to log the request from C# app via PHP based API.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoException' 
with message ''\\0' not allowed in key: \\0...'
```

After googling it for a while I came to a conclusion that I can solve it by iterating through
the array I'm trying to insert in Mongo, and replacing null terminator in keys and values.

I'm wondering is there a more elegant solution to this and how is it that Mongo cannot handle this case?

I also have `mongo.allow_empty_keys` set to 1 in my `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you a more elegant PHP solution, but the reason why this is causing a problem is because [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), and hence MongoDB uses null terminated strings, arrays etc.  Hence embedding null values is going to cause confusion in general.  These things will eventually get handled (see [SERVER-1177](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1177) for example) but even when they are I would still recommend not using nulls in general if it can be avoided - it's too easy to imagine edge cases and possible bugs when doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I did solve the problem by iterating, since I cannot otherwise control requests through API, but now I understand  the problem that I was facing.